# How to work with json data in Azure data factory

Tags: python, json, azure-data-factory

I am getting the below env_variable.json data with Lookup variable and want to get "NO","BR" programmatically to iterate in ForEach activity.The file's content is

> {"countries" :  { "NO" :  { "wells": ["0015/abcd"] },   "BR" : {
> "wells": [] } } }

I am trying to fetch it using the below command,

> @activity('Lookup for env parameters').output.firstRow.countries[0]

But getting "**The expression 'length(activity('Lookup for env parameters').output.firstRow.countries[0])' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Object properties can only be selected by names.**"

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

**--Update**

So if you want to loop on array `wells`, contained in each entry NO..BR..etc under countries dynamically, am afraid there is no explicit out-of-the-box method available to do so.

**Alternately**, to skip making this more complex, I would suggest you try a function app with a code in a language of your choice to extract the details from JSON.

---

However, once you have the user entries (`NO`, `BR`, etc...), you can try as below to access the array further.

It appears the below is of type Object and Object properties can only be selected by names.

```
"countries": {
    "NO": {
        "wells": [
            "0015/NO 15-12-1"
        ]
    },
    "BR": {
        "wells": []
    }
},
```

here is the expression you can try, explicitly select arrays within `NO` and `BR`

```
@activity('Lookup').output.value[0].countries.NO.wells
```

Create an `Array` type variable

[image]

Set variable with dynamic expression:

```
@activity('Lookup').output.value[0].countries.BR.wells
```

[image]

[image]

**Further..** you can `reference` this array variable in `Foreach` activity.

Comment: Actually, I can't use NO and BR directly, it has to be dynamically fetched. It's kind of user input which I have to fetch from env_variable.json file.

Comment: okay so you want to loop on array `wells` ? contained in each entry `NO`..`BR`..etc under `countries`

Comment: Exactly.yes.Can it be done in ADF?

Comment: Unfortunately seems like not, atleast I was not able to get it. I would suggest you try a function app with a code in a language of your choice to fetch the details.